# MySQL Connector .NET max packet size

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

I'm building a C# Application that talks to a MySQL database via the MySQL .NET Connector. Is it possible to adjust the maximum packet size of my client?

I'm aware that I could change it on the server side with

```
max_allowed_packet = value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/packet-too-large.html) yes you can set that option at client side as well provided you are using a full blown client like

```
shell> mysql --max_allowed_packet=32M
```

But for using with .NET connector that option looks to be not present. Refer [Connector/Net Connection String Options Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-connection-options.html) and you will see that `max_allowed_packet` option not present for you to set in *Connection String*.

You have the option left to set it at server side only.